# Preloading revicons.woff?5510888 and woff2

Tags: wordpress, pagespeed, preload

I finished creating the page and started to do speed optimization.
When I access pagespeed insights, the key problem is:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSttX.png

I tried to add between head

`<link rel = "preload" href = "https: //..../fa-regular-400.woff2 ″ as =" font "type =" font / woff2 ″ crossorigin />`

but without any effects, can anyone help?
I use wordpress, theme- woodmart, wp rocket

Answer (score 1):

1. Navigate to `Avada > Options > Advanced > Custom Fields (Tracking etc.)`
2. Find `Space before </head>` section
3. Paste following font code in head section:

```html
<link rel="preload" as="font" href="https://www.homepage.com/wp-content/uploads/fusion-icons/Marketing-Bold-v1.0/fonts/fa-regular-400.woff2?d5d08s" type="font/ttf" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

4. Hit `Save Changes` and re-analyze in Google PageSpeed Insioghts

**Please Note:**

- If you don't know the exact URL of font, simply copy it from Google PageSpeed Insights results (as mentioned in your screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSttX.png)
- Change `type="font/ttf"` to ttf value to woff2/ttf/woff as it showen in the end of URL.

Comment: Seems you suggestions works. At least for my website, which is using Storefront.. but, about your second note, what do you mean? could you give an example? I have changed the type="font/ttf" to type="woff2/ttf/woff" but guessing I am doing something wrong (or/and a typo one)?

Comment: It's just the type of fond or you can guess it font extension e.g. ttf/woff/woff2. So you should mention same extension in "type="font/ttf".

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, its hard to say. It is possible that Revicon.woff is used in your app for its left and right arrow icons (the rest of the font is... not ascetically popular). You should be able to find exactly where these are in your code by searching for 'revicon' in your code and all its dependencies.

Once you find the dependency loading these fonts, using the name/keyword for the dependency in your reformatted question, along with the code that loads revicon.woff, will help attract better answers than mine.